# Delete everything before the Third colon in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can one delete everything after the Third slash (/) in:

```
women/clothes/pants-shorts/sandy-beach-destroyed-denim-shorts
```

So that the line becomes:

```
sandy-beach-destroyed-denim-shorts
```

Comment: "After" or "Before",? The title and the example don't fit.

Comment: What about strings like: `part1/part2/part3/part4/part5`?

Answer (score 0):

Find :

```
^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/(.*)$
```

Replace with :

```
\1
```